# DRF - create() must be implemented

Tags: django-views, django-rest-framework

I am getting this error.

This is my views file,

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin):
        serializer_class = ItemSerializer

        def get_queryset(self):
                queryset = Item.objects.all()
                return queryset

        def create(self, request):
                serializer = ItemSerializer(data=request.data)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                        serializer.save()
                        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

But In my view, I don't get the form for creating the model,

[image]

When I click `POST`, I get `create() must be implemented.`

Comment: kindly share the serializer class and if you are using nested serializers/

Answer (score 2):

It's likely the serializer's create that must be implemented, not the view set's one.

Also note that this may indicate you're using nested serializers which aren't supported by the browsable API.

Answer (score 1):

I gusses,your `serializer` error. It must exntends `serializers.ModelSerializer`, not `serializers.Serializer`。

eg:

```py
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentApi1
        fields = ["name","age"]
```